# Summing months in PHP?

Tags: php, date

There is `$month1=10` and `$month2=4` .
If I sum those 2 months, I will get 14, but there is no month 14, it then means it's february/2.

Is there a logic or a php function that when 6+7=1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try modulus (remainder). So `(6 + 7) / 12` would equal 1

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php

Answer (score 5):

```
($month1 + $month2) % 12
                   ^^^
```

This is the [modulus operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) and it returns the remainder of the first operand divided by the second one.

Answer (score 4):

An alternative:

```
$datetime = new DateTime('October');
$datetime->add('4 months');
echo $datetime->format('%m');
```

Answer (score 1):

Modulus directly answers your question; however, for date arithmetic, you would do well to use date-specific functions:

```
$date = time();
  // or another unix timestamp
$four_months_later = strtotime("+4 months", $date);
  // still unix timestamp, now 4 months later
```